# MySQL function to select float value as integer if its decimal point is 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a column of `float` type(amount). The value can be an integer or float . I want to get the value as integer if the decimal point is 0 (eg: `value = 0.0, 1.0` etc) and need the value as decimal itself if it has got decimal points. Is there any MySQL function for this? 
The following is my query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(reason_code, ':', COALESCE(identifier, ''), '*', amount * -1)) AS accout_groups
FROM adjustments WHERE check_id = 1 GROUP BY department_id*
```

Result of query is below

`PI:*-900.00,AP:*-87.00,CS:12312312*-1500.00,SL:12312312*-1103.83`

What Iam expecting is

`PI:*-900,AP:*-87,CS:12312312*-1500,SL:12312312*-1103.83`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(reason_code, ':', COALESCE(identifier, ''), '*',(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM amount)))) * -1)) AS accout_groups FROM adjustments WHERE check_id = 1 GROUP BY department_id`

This is working